# Spring security url-interceptor

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I have the following code:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/authenticated/**/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<intercept-url pattern="/authenticated/files/**" access="none" />
```

I want spring security secure all the links derived from `/authenticated` except `authenticated/files`. Is this type of securing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move more specific condition higher:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/authenticated/files/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/authenticated/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    ...
</http>
```